# jquery change from select to type=radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is work example http://jsfiddle.net/p4stK/ or here

```
Select <select name="type" id="type" style="margin-left:57px; width:153px;">
        <option ame="first" value="first">first</option>
        <option name="second" value="second">second</option>
        <option name="computer" value="computer">computer</option>
         <option name="car" value="car">car</option>
</select>

<div id="first">Information first</div>
<div id="second">Information second</div>    
<div id="computer">Somthing about computer here</div>
<div id="car">Somthing about car here</div>
```

and

```
 $(function () {
     $('#car').hide();
     $('#computer').hide();
     $('#second').hide();
     $('#type').change(function () {
         $('#computer').hide();
         if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 'computer') {
             $('#computer').show();
         }
         $('#car').hide();
         if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 'car') {
             $('#car').show();
         }
                  $('#first').hide();
         if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 'first') {
             $('#first').show();
         }
                  $('#second').hide();
         if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 'second') {
             $('#second').show();
         }
     });
 });
```

i need this code work with type=radio like

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="check" value="first"><b>First</b><br />
<input type="radio" name="check" value="second"><b>Second</b><br />
<input type="radio" name="check" value="computer"><b>Computer</b><br />
<input type="radio" name="check" value="car"><b>Car</b>
</form>
```

Comment: the jsfiddle itself is not working.

Comment: and i need that code posted here.

Comment: work for me, i will edit and add the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
Select<input type="radio" name="check" checked value="first"/>first
<input type="radio" name="check" value="second"/>second
<input type="radio" name="check" value="computer"/>computer
<input type="radio" name="check" value="car"/>car

<div id="first">Information first</div>
<div id="second">Information second</div>    
<div id="computer">Somthing about computer here</div>
<div id="car">Somthing about car here</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
     $("#second,#computer,#car").hide();
     $("input[name='check']").click(function () {
        $("#first,#second,#computer,#car").hide();
        $("#" + this.value).show();
     });
 });
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/p4stK/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('input[name="check"]')
```

instead of:

```
$('#type')
```

and:

```
$("input[name='check']:checked").val()
```

instead of:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4stK/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the jQuery selector like below,

```
$('input[name=check]:checked').val();
```

to get the checked raido value, and other things are so easy, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(function () {
     $('#car').hide();
     $('#computer').hide();
     $('#second').hide();
     $('input[name="check"]').change(function () {

         $('#computer').hide();
         if (this.value == 'computer') {
             $('#computer').show();
         }
         $('#car').hide();
         if (this.value == 'car') {
             $('#car').show();
         }
                  $('#first').hide();
         if (this.value == 'first') {
             $('#first').show();
         }
                  $('#second').hide();
         if (this.value == 'second') {
             $('#second').show();
         }
     });
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p4stK/1/)

Comment: Or just `$('#first,#second,#computer,#car').hide();$('#'+this.value).show();` http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/p4stK/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

**HTML**

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="check" value="first"><b>First</b><br />
<input type="radio" name="check" value="second"><b>Second</b><br />
<input type="radio" name="check" value="computer"><b>Computer</b><br />
<input type="radio" name="check" value="car"><b>Car</b>
</form>

<div class="blocks" id="first">Information first</div>
<div class="blocks" id="second">Information second</div>    
<div class="blocks" id="computer">Somthing about computer here</div>
<div class="blocks" id="car">Somthing about car here</div>
```

**Script**

```
$('.blocks').hide();

$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
    $('.blocks').hide();    
    $('#'+$(this).attr('value')).show();
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fj6PM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle with a possible answer [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qpirate/9xg76/2/)

the JS is as follows

```
$(function () {
       $('div.showOnChange:not(:first)').hide();  
       $(':radio[name="check"]').change(function(e){
                 var elem = $(this);
                 $('div.showOnChange').hide();
                 $('#'+elem.val()).show();
             });
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
$("input[name=check]").click(function(){
        var divId="#"+$(this).val();
        $("div").hide();
        $(divId).show();
    });
```